# How to convert Log(g) vs T_eff to y vs (v-y)?

Tags: astrophysics, stellar-evolution, photometry

I have a plot in Log(g) vs T_eff coordinates from my stellar evolution model. The parameters of the model are M=0.8 M_solar, [Fe/H]=-1.19, Y=0.245. I want to convert it to the y vs (v-y) coordinates ([Strömgren photometric system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Str%C3%B6mgren_photometric_system)) in order to compare my model with observations of NGC 6752 globular cluster. How do I make this conversion?

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0311458v1.pdf) provides a [table](http://vizier.cfa.harvard.edu/viz-bin/VizieR?-source=J/AJ/127/1227) that includes the following columns: Log(g), T_eff, V, (B-V), (b-y), m1, c1.

I think I could use this if I can figure out how to calculate y and (v-y) from these data. Is it possible?